In Pathfinder 1e, what is the highest possible dodge bonus that a player character can get?
This question was inspired by What are the maximum bonuses of each type possible?, and is a much more specific form of that question.

In first edition Pathfinder, dodge bonuses have the distinction of being one of the few types of bonuses that stack with themselves. They also have the interesting distinction of most things that provide them having conditions attached that result in the bonus only applying in some circumstances.
Given this, I am curious what the highest possible dodge bonus to AC a player character can have is. The current best I’m able to come up with is a total of +29 with:

13 levels of Kensai Magus and an INT of 36 for a +13 from Canny Defense. The weapon selected for the Kensai must be a reach weapon (required for a later part of the optimization).
4 levels of Gunslinger to obtain the dare Frantically Nimble in place of the level 4 bonus feat the Gunslinger would normally get. Grit points are then reduced to 0 by any means possible to get a +2 from Frantically Nimble.
A DEX of 13 and the Dodge feat for +1.
A INT of 13 and the Artful Dodge feat, plus being the sole ally threatening a single opponent who is wielding a reach weapon (the reach weapon is required for a later optimization) for +1.
A INT of 13 and BAB of +5, and the Defensive Weapon Training feat, selecting the fighter weapon group that your intended opponent’s weapon is in, for +2
The Mobility (prerequisite) and Just Out of Reach feats, plus being more than 5 feet away from your opponent while both of you are wielding reach weapons and you are still threatening them for +4
Taking the Total Defense action for +4
Being a Halfling and having the Cautious Fighter feat for +2 while taking total defense

Criteria for an answer:

The total dodge bonus should be at least +18, since that much is trivially achievable with almost no conditions. I am still interested in answers that are at or above this threshold but lower than the my example of +29 above, as they may give insights into other ways to improve things further.
Prerequisites must be noted even if they do not directly increase the final total.
The build must be possible following standard rules when the criteria below do not state otherwise (for example, no doubling up on magic items in the same slot)
The character is assumed to be level 20.
Up to 880000 gold may be spent as part of the optimization (this is standard wealth-by-level for a level 20 player character).
If the character could not cast a spell that is needed for the optimization, the standard rules for spellcasting services must be used to compute the cost.
Ability scores are capped at a max of 36, but are not counted as part of the cost of optimization. Ability scores only need to be noted when they are relevant to the build.
All first-party content is permitted unless the rules explicitly disallow it’s usage by a player character or it has been excluded by the rules above.
If a given part of the optimization is open to GM interpretation, this should be explicitly noted.


I'm probably just suffering from holiday-related malaise, but this doesn't seem like a problem that needs solving. Really, the resultant character is likely to be unplayable, with resources devoted exclusively to achieving the goal. The only interesting thing that would seem to come out of all of this would be unusual sources of dodge bonuses. Could this question instead just ask that? What are additional sources of dodge bonuses? is a fine standalone question. Why make this contest-ish?

@HeyICanChan I can kind of understand where you’re coming from with that, but I would also argue that the same is largely true of many (maybe most?) optimization problems for Pathfinder 1e and D&D 3.5e. This one is admittedly a bit more theoretically focused than practical, but I personally do not see that as a significant issue.

I know for a fact that highest possible AC has been asked about D&D 5e, and I believe 3.5 as well. I believe this is distinct enough not to be a copy of that type of question if it was asked about Pathfinder already, but I know few if any of the answers to those questions were 'playable'.

Kk, here is you Baseline
Canny Defense (Magus): +13 (Requires 13 Magus levels and Int 36)
Frantically Nimble (Gunslinger): +2 (4 Gunslinger levels, 0 Grit)
Dodge: +1 (Dex 13)
Artful Dodge: +1 (Int 13, specific conditions)
Defensive Weapon Training: +2 (Int 13, BAB +5, specific conditions)
Just Out of Reach: +4 (Mobility, specific conditions)
Total Defense: +4
Cautious Fighter (Halfling): +2 (During Total Defense)
Total: +29

How to improve as I see it
Crane Style/Winged Style
Crane Style grants a dodge bonus to AC equal to your Wisdom modifier against attacks of opportunity. Winged Style builds upon this, allowing it to function against all attacks while flying. While powerful, these require specific combat maneuvers and may not always be applicable. However, with a high Wisdom, this could add a significant bonus. (Requires feats: Crane Style, Crane Wing, Winged Style)
Fighting Defensively
While not a dodge bonus, Fighting Defensively provides a +2 to AC. Since it stacks with dodge bonuses, it's worth noting for overall AC.
Arrow Deflection (Monk)
A Monk (or character with Monk's Robes) can deflect arrows with a successful Reflex save. This isn't a dodge bonus, but it can significantly reduce the chance of being hit.
Class-Specific Abilities
strong text
Certain classes (like the Duelist) offer abilities that enhance AC in specific situations, though not always as dodge bonuses. Explore these for synergistic benefits.
Magic Items
While you haven't explicitly mentioned them, certain magic items can grant dodge bonuses. These could further boost your AC.
Optimizing Your Example
Your existing build is already very strong. The main area for improvement is leveraging Wisdom with Crane Style/Winged Style. This requires a rebuild focusing on both Wisdom and Intelligence.
Example Optimized Build (Level 20)
Magus (Kensai) 13: Int 36, Canny Defense +13
Gunslinger 4: Frantically Nimble +2 (0 Grit)
Monk 3: Wis 18 (for +4 with Crane Style/Winged Style), potentially higher with items. Monk's Robes for arrow deflection.
Feats: Dodge, Artful Dodge, Defensive Weapon Training, Mobility, Just Out of Reach, Crane Style, Crane Wing, Winged Style, Cautious Fighter (if Halfling).
Total Dodge Bonus: +13 (Canny) + 2 (Frantic) + 1 (Dodge) + 1 (Artful) + 2 (DWT) + 4 (Just Out of Reach) + 4 (Crane/Winged Style) + 4 (Total Defense) + 2 (Cautious Fighter) = +33
Additional AC Bonuses: +2 Fighting Defensively.
Anyways...
This build relies heavily on specific conditions (flying, low grit, specific enemy weapons, etc.). Magic items could further enhance AC. Multiclassing comes with tradeoffs in terms of higher-level class features.
So....
Reaching a +33 dodge bonus to AC is theoretically possible with this optimized build. But remember, practicality in actual gameplay is crucial. While this build maximizes dodge bonus, it comes with significant limitations and dependencies. A slightly less optimized build with more flexibility might be more effective overall.
